# How to construct an instance of a view-model when using Asp.Net MVC 5 framework and IoC container?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, unity-container

I am writing a project using ASP.NET MVC 5 framework along with Unity-Container to handle my dependencies.

I am hunting for a best practice to deal with constructing view-models while using `IoC` container in an Asp.Net MVC 5 app. I hope this question isn't considered opinion based and gets closed.

I have the following view-model class

```
public class CategoryReportViewModel
{
    public IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<object> Records { get; set; }
    // ....

    public TasksSummaryByProductViewModel(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public void SetFilters()
    {
        // Do something.....
        UnitOfWork.....
    }

    public void SetData()
    {
        // Do something.....
        Records = UnitOfWork.....
    }
}
```

As you can see, my `CategoryReportViewModel` class needs an instance of the `IUnitOfWork` to allow my methods to to perform their task "unless I manually pass the `IUnitOfWork` to every method that needs it." I am wondering what is the right way to new up an instance of `CategoryReportViewModel`. Is it via `IoC` container or using the good-old way by passing an instance of the `IUnitOfWork` from the constructor?

In other words, what is the right way to consume my view-model?

Follow are the approaches that comes to mind when trying to deal with this scenario, but which is the right way? Perhaps there is alternative?

First, good-old manual new up strategy

```
public class ReportsController : Controller
{
    protected IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; set; }

    public ReportsController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CategoryByName()
    {
        var viewModel = new CategoryReportViewModel(UnitOfWork);

        viewModel.SetFilters();

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult CategoryByName(CategoryReportViewModel viewModel)
    {
        viewModel.UnitOfWork = UnitOfWork; // This is ugly
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            viewModel.SetData();
        }

        viewModel.SetFilters();

        return View(viewModel);
    }
}
```

Second, manual new up but pass the `UnitOfWork` to any methods that needs it

```
public class ReportsController : Controller
{
    protected IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; set; }

    public ReportsController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CategoryByName()
    {
        var viewModel = new CategoryReportViewModel();

        viewModel.SetFilters();

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult CategoryByName(CategoryReportViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            viewModel.SetData(UnitOfWork);
        }

        viewModel.SetFilters(UnitOfWork);

        return View(viewModel);
    }
}
```

Third, using `IoC` container after registering the `CategoryReportViewModel`. But this will require me to modify Asp.Net MVC 5 default behavior since my view-model may/does not have a default constructor.

```
public class ReportsController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CategoryByName()
    {
        var viewModel = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<CategoryReportViewModel>();
        viewModel.SetFilters();

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    // This will now work since I my view-model does not have a default constructor
    // unless I override the `DefaultModelBinder` class somehow to resolve the class
    // from the IoC container
    [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult CategoryByName(CategoryReportViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            viewModel.SetData();
        }

        viewModel.SetFilters();

        return View(viewModel);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's room for different approaches and opinions on this, but the pattern I've found to work best is to make the ViewModels be "dumb" DTOs whose properties are created and populated by the controller. Inject services into the controller, and have all the business logic in your action methods.

In other words, `SetFilters()` and `SetData()` should probably be on the controller, and take the model as an argument.

```
public class ReportsController : Controller
{
    protected IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; set; }

    public ReportsController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CategoryByName()
    {
        var viewModel = new CategoryReportViewModel();

        this.SetFilters(viewModel);

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult CategoryByName(CategoryReportViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            this.SetData(viewModel);
        }

        this.SetFilters(viewModel);

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    private void SetFilters(CategoryReportViewModel viewModel)
    {
        // Do something.....
        UnitOfWork.....
    }

    private void SetData(CategoryReportViewModel viewModel)
    {
        // Do something.....
        Records = UnitOfWork.....
    }
}
```

Comment: I kind of disagree/agree, I agree that his properties should be mapped through the controller via AutoMapper or manually. However, I disagree that `SetFilters()` and `SetData()` should be on the controller. ViewModel by definition can have logic for View related. Where as DTO is just a dummy model. This is my opinion.

Comment: @12seconds That's an opinion I respect. I would limit that view-related logic to requiring data available to the ViewModel itself, though. For example, an `IsAdminLinkVisible` property might be exposed, which applies some basic logic from information like whether the user has admin rights and which view mode they're in. But I wouldn't expect the ViewModel to do a database round-trip to check the current user's permissions. Whether they *have* admin rights is a domain-level concept, and should be determined by the controller (or other injected services), and provided to the ViewModel.

Comment: But wouldn't that over load the controller and reduce the code re-usability? I mean what if the business logic is more complex?

Comment: Yep that's what I kind of meant, there shouldn't be any database call in your viewmodel, for example logic in ViewModel could be perhaps be filtering small list of data what they can see based on their role which is usually store under `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity`. Or properties logic calculation methods for view related. It's just methods which is there to help your view. Anything else that is consider business logic should belong in your services layer.

Comment: @MikeA: If the business logic is more complex, then I would move it into a service in the business-logic layer. It's more reusable there anyway, because it can be used by multiple controllers. Using the example in my comment earlier, it's highly likely that multiple views are going to want to know whether the current user has admin-level permissions, whereas the decision about whether to show a given link, or what text to display there, is probably specific to a given View/ViewModel. Put the business logic (which consumes IUnitOfWork) in the business layer and the view logic in the view layer.

Comment: @12seconds: Yup. However, I would avoid using `HttpContext.Current`. That creates a hard dependency that's not explicitly declared in any constructor or method signature, and may not be available in a different thread or synchronization context (e.g. if you use `await ...ConfigureAwait(false)`). Instead, I'd have the controller provide the `User.Identity` as an argument to the method that needs to check for a given user's permissions, and set a property like `CurrentUserHasAdminPermissions` on the ViewModel.